# How to invite people to an event who don't get along?

Tags: friends, united-states, invitations, birthdays

I'm hosting an event in a couple of weeks - my son's first birthday party. I have several people who I would like to invite. Unfortunately, some of them don't get along. This seems to be a one-sided disagreement - meaning that Person A doesn't like Family B for some slight that Person A can't get past. I'm not involved in the disagreement and don't completely understand it but my husband and I regularly interact with both Person A and Family B and would like to invite them both to the event.

Neither of these parties are family. They are both friends. Person A was in our wedding and Family B hosted our baby shower for our son, so both are part of our close circle of friends. Person A did not attend the baby shower but that was at Family B's home while this event is at our home.

So, I see a few ways of this turning out.

1. **I invite both but don't tell Person A**.
   Person A may or may not get grumpy at me for not telling them in advance but they are both at the party. Person A may depart early rather than being around Family B.
2. **I invite both and tell Person A.**
   Person A will likely not come to the party. I would be disappointed in this outcome. Person A may still be grumpy at me for inviting Family B, "preventing them" from coming to the party.
3. **Don't invite Family B.**
   I've already given an invite to Person A, so the opposite of this isn't possible. This feels like I'm getting in the middle of the "feud" and picking sides.

So, how should I handle this? Is there some alternate solution that I'm not seeing here? I don't really feel like I should be even having to deal with this. They are all adults, so perhaps I'm over-thinking things. I trust them all to be gracious at the party and not make a scene, so perhaps option 1 is the best choice... but I feel like full disclosure might be more fair to Person A.

Comment: Is talking to one (say A) and explain you don't want them to be bothered with B, and that you will hold a second event especially for them, something you can think of ?

Comment: @OldPadawan I'm not sure how I would hold a second birthday party. Do note that on SE we welcome all answers, so even if the answer doesn't work for me, someone else may be in a similar situation, so that may work for them. I've certainly heard of people using a solution similar to that.

Comment: What is the nature of this event? A dinner in a table? An indoor and outdoor party? Can you "separate" A and B so A doesn't have to see B (even though he know B will be coming)?

Comment: @Vylix It's just... a party... kid parties in the US don't usually involve sit-down dinners. Just a bunch of people hanging out in a house, decorations, snacks... hoping the kid doesn't have a melt down. That sort of thing.

Comment: Oh, okay, somehow I didn't see that even it's on the very first line of your post ;)

Comment: How many people are you inviting? Will they all know each other? Also, you mention "Family B" but only "Person A"—does that mean there are more than two B's, and A will be coming solo?

Comment: @1006a Person A occasionally brings a spouse but I don't know that they have the same concerns. I say "Family B" because there are three of them and he seems disinterested in seeing all of them, not just a single member of the family, even though his complaint is limited to a single member of the family.

Comment: `It is their son's first birthday party! That is not the place to start a fight.` Brandon's comment really makes me wonder, is kind of people that will not behave if he met someone he dislike? Maybe your concern is too much? (Although you want to make everyone get along, maybe he will be grumpy but not making a scene) What is your goal here?

Comment: What you mean by "don't like"? There are some people I don't like, and usually when I encounter them we usually have some polite small talk then proceed to ignore one another. Not liking doesn't mean instantly starting a fight.

Comment: BTW. Are there other people invited? If so, "Person A" might just hang out with neutral people and simply not interact with "Family B". There's no rule that every guest must has to interact with every other guest, isn't it?

Comment: Unfortunately, this question appears to be asking “What should I do?”, which the community has [determined](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1310/31) to not be a good fit for Interpersonal Skills Stack Exchange. We can’t decide for you what to do; after you determine what you want to do, we can help you with your goal, but we can’t make these decisions for you. Sorry.

Answer (score 16):

Option 2 sounds like the safest and most honest way to handle it.

If Person A is likely to be uncomfortable, but you still want them to show up, it's probably better if you give them a chance to prepare rather than be surprised by the situation.

Just break it to them tactfully and express how important it is to you that they be there. Of course you can't make them show up, or get along with Family B, but you can express that it's important to you and that you're sure everyone is mature enough to temporarily bury the hatchet and play nice for your sake.

I'm often "Person A" at my family's gatherings... Usually my cousin plays your part. I simply don't get along with a lot of her people, but she's usually *coercive* enough to get everyone to show up and behave.

It usually goes something like this:

> Cousin: Hey it's SoAndSo's birthday, you're coming right?
>   Me: You sure that's a good idea? You know I don't get along with X,Y, and Z.
>   Cousin: Yes X, Y, and Z will be there, but you'll behave and so will they.
>   Cousin: You're coming.
>   Me: Ehh...
>   Cousin: You know this means a lot to me and I'll kick your butt if you don't show up...
>   Me: Alright... If I have to...
>   Cousin: Great! Bring rolls, or beer!

Comment: This sounds like a good solution but I think your situation is different because you're dealing with family. I don't have that same bantering relationship with Person A. It's also not that they don't get along *generally*... they used to be good friends long before I ever met them both... and they've since had a falling out - which is one-sided and they haven't even really explained to Family B *why* they are ignoring them.

Comment: @Catija playing the peacemaker would make for a really good follow-up question. The wording is of course quite optional, I assumed banter would work because friends often communicate that way.

Comment: Any time I mention Family B to Person A they just stop talking. This isn't something that can be "bantered" about. Person A is ones of those people who makes a decision about someone and then refuses to change their mind, even if no one understands their reasoning. I really do think this is a good solution I'm just not sure if it will work for me!

Answer (score 7):

*I find "A" and "B" a bit impersonal, so I'll call them Alice and Bob.*

### Invite Them Separately

Invite Alice at an earlier time than Bob and most of the guests, and tell Alice that Bob will be coming. That way, Alice can plan her visit early and leave before Bob arrives.

#### Rationale

You don't want to invite them both at the same time and have to play the peacekeeper. And since the animosity is not reciprocated by Bob, it would be unfair to punish Bob for it.

Especially with big occasions like your son's first birthday, you'll likely have people arriving at different times, so other guests may not even notice.

#### Alternative

An alternative would be to invite Alice on a separate occasion. Alice is the bad actor here, so she should be the one to adjust.

Comment: Whether it's unfair to punish Bob would in large part depend Catija's view on what Bob did to Alice to annoy her/him so much. But, of course, Catija doesn't know.

Answer (score 3):

## Invite Both

You've already invited *Person A*, and retracting that invitation wouldn't be acceptable.

*Family B* is important to you as well, and not inviting them would be unfair to yourself, and your family. It would also be a slight to them that they don't deserve.

## Talk to *Person A*

*Person A* deserves to know that *Family B* will be there. To not say something, when you *do* know that the feelings exist, does not seem like a good thing for a "friend" to do. However, in talking to *Person A* express how you feel, that you're "walking on egg shells" trying to not cause problems.

In having that discussion, try to keep your statements in the format of explaining how you feel, and what you do first, and the cause of that (their actions) second. Leading with their actions first tends to place them in a defensive mode, and from that stance there is very little hope of compromise or change.

Explain how it feels unfair to you that you have to either choose who to invite, or plan the party so that they're not offended, or worry that they won't come because of someone else at the party. Just because of what some member of *Family B* did to *Person A* in the past. *Person A* was there for the beginning of your family (wedding), so explain that it's important to you that they be there to celebrate another milestone of your family.

---

You cannot force change, yet you may be the agent of change. Perhaps, seeing how it affects you, making you nervous and unsure, might cause *Person A* to examine their stance relative to *Family B*. If so, wonderful. If not, your part is done, and you have been reasonable and fair.

Answer (score 1):

We actually just went through this not too long ago with our little one's 1st birthday. Personally I feel the best answer is just to be completely honest with all parties. In our situation, it was grandma and grandpa who don't get along anymore. Their 1st grandson's 1st birthday party from their 1st daughter.

I say remind them this party is not about the issues they have with each other. It's about celebrating someone special in their life and they really should be there. Let them know that there's going to be plenty of other people to talk to and they'll be able to gracefully avoid each other. For example:

"Hi (PERSON A)! Hey I just wanted to remind you that  has a birthday party coming up and you should really be there! It's going to be at (A NEUTRAL LOCATION LIKE A PARK) and we'll have games and cake and ice cream... a bunch of people have already said they're coming so you can't be the one who doesn't show!"

... Now pause for a moment. If they react quickly and ask about PERSON B, you'll have to work extra hard, good luck. Otherwise, you can start listing names of people who are going to show, and some who you invited but don't know for sure yet. Wherever PERSON B fits in to that list, throw their name in there, but without emphasis! Practice this before you try it. You'll find you subconsciously make PERSON B stick out of the group one way or another.

I wish you luck. Our situation didn't work out with both being present. :(

Comment: Sorry to hear that it didn't work out. You have a good approach: honesty, focus on the reason for the celebration, open location so people with conflicts don't have to be very near each other. It's up to the parties involved to sort out their differences. You can hope (and if appropriate, voice it to them) that they wouldn't drag it into *your* happy occasion.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed two contradictory statements:

1. This seems to be a one-sided disagreement - meaning that Person A doesn't like Family B for some slight that Person A can't get past.
2. I'm not involved in the disagreement and don't completely understand it

You say that you do not completely understand the disagreement, yet you are holding Person A responsible.  Maybe if you fully understood the disagreement, you would understand why Person A thinks it is impossible to be around Family B.

Hypothetically speaking, if Family B did something *bullying* towards Person A, you could be piling-on by holding Person A accountable before understanding the facts.

If it were me, and a friend tricked me into having to be around people that I had felt bullied by, I would be very upset.

Comment: No, that's not really what I mean. Person A has explained why they're upset at family B, I just don't understand why it's worth being upset over... it seems really petty and small.

Comment: In that case, if you are at the point where you would consider tricking her into joining company that she does not want to, it seems that you've lost respect for her as an adult. In this way, you have become party to the conflict. It seems that there is something for you two to resolve;  since friendship is based on being able to respect each other.

Answer (score 0):

## Be as open as possible.

Surprising A or B with the other's presence **invites** chaos. The fact is, if these people are truly your friends, they will respect you enough to not cause drama. You should just make it clear that this is your son's birthday party and that it isn't about either of them. If they can't play nice for a couple hours to celebrate with you, it may be time to consider if they are really your friends. That is not to say that they are bad friends if they don't show up. However, if they do both show up to the party, knowing that they will run into each other at some point, and still cause problems, I believe that shows a lack of respect towards you and your family.

Answer (score 0):

As you said:

> I don't really feel like I should be even having to deal with this. They are all adults...

It is your son's party, not theirs. And you are not a party to their conflict.

I would say invite them both and don't show any preference. If either can't be civil, then just tell them (in private) their behavior is disrupting the party, and if it doesn't stop there's the door.

I think any other interaction will show some favoritism which will not help matters.

Also it might be helpful to have enough activities, food, etc. that might hopefully keep them distracted from their personal problems.